# How to configure UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter using java code?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I googled UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter , and what I saw is the xml-based configurations for using UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter. My application uses java-based config :

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }

}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ambre.pta")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/global.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/main.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/admin.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/referentiel.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/departement.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/exercice.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/defi.properties")
})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    /**
     * méthode permettant d'accéder les fichiers de ressources tels que les langues
     * @return un gestionnaire de fichiers de ressources
     */
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    /**
     * méthode permettant de préciser l'emplacement et l'extension des vues jsp
     * @return un gestionnaire de vue
     */
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * méthode permettant de spécifier la connexion à la base de données
     * @return un gestionnaire de connexion à la base de données
     */
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        dataSource.setUsername("pta");
        dataSource.setPassword("pta");

        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * méthode permettant d'obtenir un gestionnaire de session hibernate
     * @param dataSource instance de la connexion à la base de données
     * @return un gestionnaire de session hibernate
     */
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.ambre.pta.model");

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

    }

    /**
     * méthode permettant de gérer automatiquement la gestion de transaction dans les requêtes sans plus avoir à commencer, valider ou annuler la transaction
     * @param sessionFactory le gestionnaire de session hibernate
     * @return un gestionnaire automatique de transaction
     */
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;

    }

    /**
     * permet d'instancier un objet d'accès aux données qu'on peut utiliser dans les controleurs
     * @param sessionFactory le gestionnaire de session hibernate
     * @return un objet d'accès aux données
     */
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "utilisateurDao")
    public UtilisateurDAO getUtilisateurDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UtilisateurDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

}
```

So how to configure UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter in my case ?

Answer (score 1):

Just [set target data source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html#setTargetDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-) with its credentials

```
@Bean("ucDataSource")
public UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter getUCDataSource(){
    UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter adapter = new UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter();
    adapter.setTargetDataSource(getDataSource());
    adapter.setUsername("pta");
    adapter.setPassword("pta");
    return adapter;
}
```

and wire up a filter set the user credentials

```
public class CredentialsFilter implements Filter{
    private UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter;
    public UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter getDataSourceAdapter() {
        return dataSourceAdapter;
    }

    public void setDataSourceAdapter(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter) {
        this.dataSourceAdapter = dataSourceAdapter;
    }
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

        if(authentication != null){
            Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
            Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();
            dataSourceAdapter.setCredentialsForCurrentThread(
                    principal.toString(), credentials.toString());
        }
        try{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally{
            dataSourceAdapter.removeCredentialsFromCurrentThread();
        }
    }
}
```

Declare a filter bean

```
@Bean    
public FilterRegistrationBean credentialFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new CredentialsFilter());
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(1); 
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```